# Is it possible to program node.js synchronously?

Tags: node.js

My coding style is apparently synchronous. If I have the following code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node

/*
 * AUTHOR  : 
 * CREATED :
 * VERSION :
 * PURPOSE :
 */

'use strict';

var $COLUMNS = 3;
var $people = [];

function main() {
    readFile('data.csv');
    printFile();
    writeFile();        
}

function readFile($filePath) {
    var $IN = require('ya-csv');
    var $reader = $IN.createCsvFileReader($filePath, {
        separator: ','
    });
    $reader.on('data', function($item) {
        $people.push($item);
    }).on('end', function() {
        console.dir($people);
    });
}

function printFile() {
    for (var $i = 0; $i < $people.length; $i++) {
        for (var $j = 0; $j < $COLUMNS; $j++) {
            process.stdout.write($people[$i][$j] + ' ');
        }
        process.stdout.write('\n');
    }
}

function writeFile() {
    var $OUT = require('ya-csv');
    var $writer = $OUT.createCsvFileWriter('dataX.csv', {
        quote: ''
    });
    $people.forEach(function($item) {
        $writer.writeRecord($item);
    });
}

main();
```

Is it possible to use the values in $people globally and use dispatching with main() like I am?

Comment: Not really... unless you want to modify `ya-csv`, but there is no reason to do so.  Use callbacks correctly.  The modifications will take you 2 minutes, and then you don't have to worry about it anymore.  Alternatively, use a promise library with some flow control.

Comment: Can you please give me a quick example of what you mean using the above code?

Comment: Have `function readFile(filePath, callback)` and then in your code when that function is done, `callback(people)`.